# Downloaded image not viewable by using WSO2 EI file connector

Tags: image, file, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am downloading image to local folder by using WSO2 EI File Connector, Image getting downloaded successfully but it is not viewable. Anyone please help me?

- getting image URL(eg. https://carsales.pxcrush.net/dealerweb/car/cil/cc5754691391091045492.jpg)  from Database.
- getting base64 content from imageURL
- then inserting those content into local folder using file connector.

**Note:** Bae64 comes from API which is not included here. base64 content is correct only, because i can get exact image from this base64 by using [base64 to Image converter](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter) 
Added below in axis2.xml file.

```
<messageFormatter contentType="application/octet-stream" class="org.apache.axis2.format.BinaryFormatter"/>
    <messageBuilder contentType="application/octet-stream" class="org.apache.axis2.format.BinaryBuilder"/>
```

**Code Snippet:**

```
<sequence name="DownloadImageFileSequnce" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="===DownloadImageFileSequnce" value="called=="/>
    </log>
            <property value="D:\Test\CarSalesStockImages" name="PATH"/>
            <property expression="get-property('StockNo')" name="FOLDERNAME"/>
            <property expression="get-property('eachImageName')" name="FILENAME"/>
            <property expression="get-property('image_val')" name="CONTENT"/>

    <!-- <property name="messageType" value="application/octet-stream" scope="axis2"/> -->
    <property expression="fn:concat('file://',$ctx:PATH,'/',$ctx:FOLDERNAME,'/',$ctx:FILENAME)" name="source"/>
        <log level="custom">
        <!-- <property name="===CONTENT===" expression="get-property('CONTENT')"/> -->
        <property name="===PATH===" expression="get-property('PATH')"/>
        <property name="===FOLDERNAME===" expression="get-property('FOLDERNAME')"/>
        <property name="===FILENAME===" expression="get-property('FILENAME')"/>
        <property name="===source===" expression="get-property('source')"/>
    </log>
        <fileconnector.isFileExist>
                <source>{$ctx:source}</source>
            </fileconnector.isFileExist>
            <property expression="json-eval($.fileExist)" name="exists" type="BOOLEAN"/>
            <filter xpath="$ctx:exists">
                <then>
                    <fileconnector.append>
                        <destination>{$ctx:source}</destination>
                        <inputContent>{$ctx:CONTENT}</inputContent>
                    </fileconnector.append>
                    <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                        <format>{"status":"File updated"}</format>
                        <args/>
                    </payloadFactory>
                    <log level="custom">
                    <property name="==Response==" expression="json-eval($.)"/>
                    </log>
                </then>
                <else>
                    <fileconnector.create>
                        <source>{$ctx:source}</source>
                        <inputContent>{$ctx:CONTENT}</inputContent>
                    </fileconnector.create>
                    <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                        <format>{"status":"File created"}</format>
                        <args/>
                    </payloadFactory>
                    <log level="custom">
                    <property name="==Response==" expression="json-eval($.)"/>
                    </log>
                </else>
            </filter>
</sequence>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution by using vfs instead of wso2 file connector.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="DownloadImageFileSequnce" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="===DownloadImageFileSequnce" value="called=="/>
    </log>
    <property name="PATH" scope="default" type="STRING" value="D:\Test\CarSalesStockImages"/>
    <property expression="get-property('StockNo')" name="FOLDERNAME" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <property expression="get-property('eachImageName')" name="FILENAME" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <property expression="get-property('image_val')" name="CONTENT" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
            <ns:binary xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">$1</ns:binary>
        </format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:CONTENT"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    <script language="js"><![CDATA[var binaryNode =       
      mc.getEnvelope().getBody().getFirstElement().getFirstOMChild();  
   binaryNode.setBinary(true);]]></script>
    <!-- <property expression="concat($ctx:PATH,'/',$ctx:FOLDERNAME,'/',$ctx:FILENAME)" name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" scope="transport" type="STRING"/> -->
    <property expression="concat('vfs:file:///',$ctx:PATH,'/',$ctx:FOLDERNAME,'/',$ctx:FILENAME)" name="localpath"/>
     <header name="To" expression="get-property('localpath')"/>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="$ctx:localpath" name="==ReplyFileName==="/>
    </log>
    <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
    <property action="remove" name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2"/>
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/octet-stream"/>
    <call/>
    <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>
                {                
                    "status": "success",                
                    "statusMessage" : "Image downloaded"               
                }            
             </format>
        <args/>
    </payloadFactory>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="json-eval($.)" name="Response"/>
    </log>

</sequence>
```

Comment: Could you please share the part of downloading image from the URL? The above snippet is only the part of reading the file from local file only

Comment: Hi @MinhTrần
Please have a look on this blog to download image from url: https://ruwansrants.blogspot.com/2014/02/mediators-how-to-use-enrich-mediator-to.html